# Why is my parameter assumed to be of one type when it is actually another?

Tags: typescript, three.js

Why do I have to hack the type definition from `material: Material | Material[];` to `material: Material;` to fix the error detailed below? TypeScript is seemingly assuming that the `material` parameter is of type `Material[]` even when I explicitly set it to Material. Am I missing something?

**Typescript/ThreeJS Error:**

```
this.obj3D.traverse((child) => {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        // Error in line below:
        // Property 'shading' does not exist on type 'Material | Material
        child.material.shading = THREE.SmoothShading;
        child.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
        child.scale.set(this.scale, this.scale, this.scale);
        child.castShadow = this.castShadow;
        child.receiveShadow = true;
        child.material.needsUpdate = true;
    }
});
```

**ThreeJS Type Definition:**

```
export class Mesh extends Object3D {
    constructor(geometry?: Geometry, material?: Material | Material[]);
    constructor(geometry?: BufferGeometry, material?: Material | Material[]);

    geometry: Geometry | BufferGeometry;
    material: Material | Material[]; // Had to delete *| Material[]* to fix
    drawMode: TrianglesDrawModes;

    setDrawMode(drawMode: TrianglesDrawModes): void;
    updateMorphTargets(): void;
    getMorphTargetIndexByName(name: string): number;
    raycast(raycaster: Raycaster, intersects: any): void;
}
```

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Rabbid76. I've updated the question and replaced the pictures with actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your screenshots, the `material` property of a `Mesh` object could either be a `Material` object *or an array of `Material` objects*.  TypeScript is helpfully warning you that you are treating `child.material` as a single `Material` object without checking if it actually is one.

Unless you are absolutely sure that every instance of `Mesh` your code will ever touch has a single `Material` object and not an array as its `material` property, it's a bad idea for you to alter the type definition in the library.  If the library declaration file is correct and some `Mesh` objects have arrays of `Material` objects, your code will behave incorrectly at runtime as soon as you try to set the `shading` property of an array.

Instead, the right thing to do would be to check whether `child.material` is an array, like:

```
  const doStuffToMaterial = function(m: Material):void {
     m.shading = THREE.SmoothShading; 
     m.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
  }
  // check for an array
  if (Array.isArray(child.material)) {
    child.material.forEach(doStuffToMaterial);
  } else {
    doStuffToMaterial(child.material);
  }
```

which handles the array case by performing the same action on each element.

Or, if you're sure that `child.material` is *not* an array, you can do something like:

```
  // Assert that it's not an array
  const m = child.material as Material; 
  m.shading = THREE.SmoothShading; 
  m.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

where you tell TypeScript you know that `child.material` is not an array, by using a type assertion.  This could still do bad things at runtime if your assertion turns out to be wrong, but presumably you know better.

I hope one of those solutions works for you.  Good luck!